# Apache rewrite root static files from /static/root/ on Redhat OpenShift

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, openshift

I am using [this project](https://github.com/openshift/bottle-openshift-quickstart) deployed on Redhat Openshift with mod_wsgi + apache

The rewrite files is placed  at `/wsgi/.htaccess` which  content is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wsgi/static/root/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ static/root/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

as you can see, I want to rewrite

```
http://mysite/favicon.ico
```

To this location on server

```
wsgi/static/root/favicon.ico
```

However my config doesn't work at all. Every static path I tried won't be catched by this rule. Since I can not `strace` apache on Redhat Openshift, so I can not tell what went wrong.

Any help? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I managed to `strace -fp $APACHE_PID` and found out how:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/root%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule . static/root%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
```

There are several trials and errors.

1. `REQUEST_FILENAME` turned out to be local file path. so use `REQUEST_URI` instead`
2. OpenShift defined `DocumentRoot` to the project `wsgi` dir
3. and `Rewriterule` shoud not use `$1` for the RegEx match because it will be mapped to `static/root/application/file_path`. I guess the mod_wsgi did some funny alias with that.

Answer (score 0):

And what about specifying the rewriteBASE ?